# seaborn boxplot: Change color and shape of mean

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

Simple question that I cannot seem to find the answer to.

How do I change the color and shape of the mean indicator in a Seaborn Boxplot?

It defaults to a Green Triangle and it generally difficult to see.

I've tried to find the answer in both the seaborn documentation, as well as the matplotlib documentation. There is also a related question on stackoverflow where someone asked how to change around colors related to the seaborn boxplots and was able to change everything except for the mean indicator.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = [[np.random.rand(100)] for i in range(3)]

sns.boxplot(data=data, showmeans=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: Seaborn Boxplot]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The keyword argument you are looking for is `meanprops`. It is in the [matplotlib boxplot documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html) under "other parameters":

```
import seaborn as sns

data = [[np.random.rand(100)] for i in range(3)]

sns.boxplot(data=data, showmeans=True,
            meanprops={"marker":"s","markerfacecolor":"white", "markeredgecolor":"blue"})

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You're the best! Thanks!

Comment: so `seaborn` boxplot is nothing more that a `plt.boxplot`